# IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 JavaScript debugger error

Tags: javascript, debugging, backbone.js, intellij-idea

Debugging a Backbone.js app with IntelliJ IDEA Chrome plugin i encountered this error at same point. Some variables, when using breakpoints, have the following value:

**`Internal error: org.jetbrains.concurrency.Promise$MessageError: Helper script failed on remote: _jb_debug_helper is not defined`**

Nevertheless the code is executed correctly. But when i need to watch the values of these variables the debugger becomes useless.

Using `console.log(var)`, the specific value is printed as expected, but only when the debug mode is finished. 
The problem appears when the application is used inside an iframe. Maybe depends on a syncronization issue.

Comment: I have the same problem, in an Angular JS application.

Comment: What's up with this bug?

Comment: They claim the fix will be included in 2017.2.3 EAP, available next week.  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27962

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem [has been fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27884) and will be released in 2017.2.3.